# Retrieve list/rows of values from "select" stored procedure , where stored procedure Function is auto generated from Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures

How to **retrieve list/rows of values from "select" stored procedure Function** , where stored procedure Function is **auto generated from Entity Framework**

I can't retrieve list of values from Stored Procedure Function,I am stucked in some part of code, where Store procedure Function is Auto Generated using Entity FrameWork
Kindly check the code attached and help me to solve this.
Thanks in Advance

```
create procedure [dbo].[SP_MobileList]
(
@MobileId varchar(50) out,
@MobileName varchar(50) out
)
As
Begin
select @MobileId=MobileId,@MobileName=MobileName from BasicMobileData
END
```

**AutoGenerated Code from Entity Framework**

```
//ModelClass
    public partial class BasicMobileData
    {
        public string MobileId { get; set; }
        public string MobileName { get; set; }
        public string MobileIMEno { get; set; }
        public decimal MobilePrice { get; set; }
    }

//In Context
    public virtual DbSet<BasicMobileData> BasicMobileDatas { get; set; }

    //Here it returns single integer value 
    **public virtual int SP_MobileList(ObjectParameter mobileID, ObjectParameter mobileName)
     {
     return((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("SP_MobileList", mobileID, mobileName);
    }**
```

**Controller Code**

```
public class MobileController : Controller
{
    MobileEntities objMobileContext = new MobileEntities();
    BasicMobileData objBasicMobileData = new BasicMobileData();

    #region "ActionMethods"
    public ActionResult MobileDetails()
    {
        ObjectParameter objParMobileId = new ObjectParameter("MobileId",typeof(string));
        ObjectParameter objParMobileName = new ObjectParameter("MobileName", typeof(string));

        //I am Stucked in this part of code
        // this "foreach" will not work since ,autogenerated "SP_MobileList(,)" is returning single integer value"
        foreach(BasicMobileData objBasicMobileData  in objMobileContext.SP_MobileList(objParMobileId,objParMobileName)){}
        return View();
    }
    #endregion        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution and its working

Changed stored procedure

```
create procedure [dbo].[SP_MobileList]
As
Begin
select MobileId,MobileName from BasicMobileData
END
```

then auto generated Stored Procedure

```
 public virtual ObjectResult<SP_MobileIdName_s_Result> SP_MobileIdName_s()
{
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<SP_MobileIdName_s_Result>("SP_MobileIdName_s");
}

public partial class SP_MobileIdName_s_Result
{
   public string MobileId { get; set; }
   public string MobileName { get; set; }
}
```

In Controller

```
public class MobileController : Controller
    {
        MobileEntities objMobileContext = new MobileEntities();
        SP_MobileIdName_s_Result objMobile = new SP_MobileIdName_s_Result();

        #region "ActionMethods"
        public ActionResult MobileDetails()
        {
            foreach (SP_MobileIdName_s_Result objMobile in objMobileContext.SP_MobileIdName_s())
            {
                Response.Write(objMobile.MobileId);
                Response.Write(objMobile.MobileName);
            }
            return View();
        }
        #endregion

    }
```

Comment: @To_All **Here Auto generated Stored-procedure  Return ObjectResult<SP_MobileIdName_s_Result>**                                     where  "SP_MobileIdName_s_Result" is a auto-generated Models, which contains all member-types  which is returning from stored Procedure function

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

> EXEC sp_help SP_MobileList

which lists you parameter used in the procedure/function

Comment: thanks for the replay,can you explain how can we use  this here

Comment: can you explain how can we use "EXEC sp_help SP_MobileList" here.